# How do I find the salesforce package prefix using the sforce or suds python libraries?

Tags: python, salesforce

I need to update some custom fields of `salesforce` objects. For that I am trying to use the `upsert` method. I am little confused on choosing the module; `SforceEnterpriseClient` or `SforcePartnerClient` of `sforce`. I think I am gonna need the name of the `package prefix` first to `upsert`. I need to do these things using `sforce` or `suds`. A little explanation on the `sforce` and `suds` tricks will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [beatbox](http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-beatbox/) library ? It is simpler than salesforce-python-toolkit

[This is a full sample](http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-beatbox/source/browse/trunk/examples/demo.py) of how to upsert a custom field:

```
import sys
import beatbox
import xmltramp
import datetime

sf = beatbox._tPartnerNS
svc = beatbox.Client()
class BeatBoxDemo:
        def login(self, username, password):
                self.password = password
                loginResult = svc.login(username, password)
                print "sid = " + str(loginResult[sf.sessionId])
                print "welcome " + str(loginResult[sf.userInfo][sf.userFullName])
        def upsert(self):
                print "\nupsert"
                t = { 'type': 'Task', 
                          'ChandlerId__c': '12345', 
                          'subject': 'BeatBoxTest updated', 
                          'ActivityDate' : datetime.date(2006,2,20) }

                ur = svc.upsert('ChandlerId__c', t)
                print str(ur[sf.success]) + " -> " + str(ur[sf.id])

                t = {   'type': 'Event', 
                        'ChandlerId__c': '67890', 
                        'durationinminutes': 45, 
                        'subject': 'BeatBoxTest', 
                        'ActivityDateTime' : datetime.datetime(2006,2,20,13,30,30),
                        'IsPrivate': False }
                ur = svc.upsert('ChandlerId__c', t)
                if str(ur[sf.success]) == 'true':
                        print "id " + str(ur[sf.id])
                else:
                        print "error " + str(ur[sf.errors][sf.statusCode]) + ":" +        str(ur[sf.errors][sf.message])

if __name__ == "__main__":

        if len(sys.argv) != 3:
                print "usage is demo.py <username> <password>"
        else:
                demo = BeatBoxDemo()
                demo.login(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])       
                demo.upsert()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, really appreciate it. I have noticed that `beatbox` doesn't need the `security token` (from above code). Is it a good thing or bad, security wise?

Comment: As others SF SOAP API's implementation `beatbox` **DOES need** the `security token`, you should append it to password on login. Pls, take a more extensive reading of this: http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-beatbox/source/browse/trunk/README.txt

Comment: Didn't notice that. My bad!. Thanks